# Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a precompact but not compact subset of $(C[(a,b]),|| \cdot ||_{\infty})$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is the following

> Let $M>0$ and $N>0$ be constants. Define
>   $$
> \mathcal{F} = \{f \in C^1([a,b])\ |\ ||f||_{\infty} \leq M,||f'||_{\infty} \leq N\}
> $$
>   Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a precompact but not compact subset of $(C[(a,b]),|| \cdot ||_{\infty})$

I believe that from the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, the set is precompact. **Now I am trying to prove that it isn't closed to conclude that it is not compact.** Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Show that there exists some $g$ such that $\| g\|_ \infty =M$ and $\|g' \|_\infty <N$. [This can be done by picking some function and adding the right constant].

Consider the sequence $f_n=\frac{n-1}{n}g$.

Answer (score 1):

It is open because $f \to (\|f\|_{\infty},\|f'\|_{\infty})$ is a continuous map. An open  subset of a normed linear pace cannot be closed  (by connectedness of the space) unless it is empty or the whole space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain more on why "It is open because $f \to (\|f\|_{\infty},\|f'\|_{\infty})$ is a continuous map"?

Comment: And does it work if I change the condition to $$\mathcal{F} = \{f \in C^1([a,b])\ |\ ||f||_{\infty} \leq M,||f'||_{\infty} \leq N\}$$?

Comment: If $f_n \to f$ in the norm of $C^{1}[a,b]$ it is clear that $\|f_n\|_{\infty} to \|f\|_{\infty}$ and $\|f_n'| to \|f'_\|{\infty}$. So the map I mentioned is continuous map from $C^{1}[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R^{2}$ . The given set  is the inverse image under this function of $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^{2}:x<N.y<M\}$.

Comment: So I guess this will not work if the inequality contains the equality.

Comment: @UnbelieveTable Right. The question is quite different if you change $<$ to $\leq $.